# How to increase font size in mobile switch?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to increase the size of the switch because it is not big enough to read on some smaller screens. Ideally it would be around double the size, however after a certain point the text does not become larger.

HTML:

```
    <div id="switch">
        <select name="flip-min" id="flip-min" data-role="slider">
            <option class="switchTxt" value="off">Images Off</option>
            <option class="switchTxt" value="on">Images On</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #switch {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:1%;
        left:1%;
    }
    .ui-li .ui-btn-inner a.ui-link-inherit, .ui-li-static.ui-li {
        display: block;
        padding: 0.9em 75px 0.9em 15px;
    }
    #switch .ui-slider-switch { 

        width:.2em;
        font-size:800px;
    }
    .switchTxt {
        font-size:500px;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rAGyC/

Comment: Somthing like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/rAGyC/1/ ?

Comment: @ezanker Yes! Please put it as an answer so I can choose it. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I added a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/rAGyC/1/)**

Given standard switch markup:

```
<div id="switch">
    <select name="flip-min" id="flip-min" data-role="slider">
        <option class="switchTxt" value="off">Images Off</option>
        <option class="switchTxt" value="on">Images On</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The CSS increases the slider size to allow for the larger text, increases the switch handle to fit the new size and finally increases the font. 32px is double the default 16px size:

```
#switch .ui-slider {
    width: 240px;
    height: 60px;
}
#switch .ui-slider-handle {
    width: 40px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0;
}
#switch .ui-slider-inneroffset {
    margin: 1px;
    margin-right: 43px;
}
#switch .ui-slider-label { 
    font-size:32px;
}
```